# gsub en dash in R/Shiny

Tags: r, regex, shiny

I am attempting to provide some links in a shiny app table that then get parsed via a text input. I get a url from a csv, render it in a data table as a link like so:

`paste0("<a href='",link_1,"'>Link</a>")`

Then the user copies the link and pastes it into a text input, which is used in a function. Somewhere in the above process, the en dashes in the links get jumbled and turned it this character string: `%C2%96`, which prevents my function from running correctly.

My workaround for this was to use `gsub` on the url to change `%C2%96` back to an en dash, but I have not been able to get it to work.

I have tried the following, with varying results:

`gsub("%C2%96", "\u2013", url)` - this turns the string into `â€“` instead of an en dash. This does it both in the console and the Shiny session.

However, if I run `paste(url_first_half, "\u2013", url_second_half)` it returns a correctly encoded url.

`gsub("%C2%96", "–", url)` - directly copying an en dash has the same effect as above, turning the string into `â€“`.

I have my server code saved with UTF-8 encoding. How can I correctly return an en dash via `gsub`?

Comment: have you checked out `?iconv` as a possible solution?  `iconv("\u2013", to = "ASCII//TRANSLIT")` returns an en dash (on linux box w/ R 3.3.2)

Comment: the `%96` is the output of `URLencode("–")`. you can convert it back with `URLdecode("%96")`

Comment: Where would I implement those solutions? There is no issue getting an en dash, i.e. if I run "\u2013" in the console I get an en dash (w/ all encoding thus far) and `print("\u2013")` in my server code logs an en dash in the console as well. But in gsub it does not come through.

Comment: Weird. Does it work with the option `useBytes=TRUE` in `gsub` ?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent It does not. It still returns `â€“`. Does it work for you?

Comment: Me I don't have this problem at all. It looks like an encoding issue, this is always painful.

Comment: @moman822 Did you try to replace `url` with `URLdecode(url)`?